# Steam won't open on Ubuntu 16.04 NO ERROR

Tags: steam

So my Steam just died yesterday. So after I could not find what was missing, I did a purge, and then I reinstalled it.

```
miguel@miguel-ThinkPad-X230:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Startup - updater built Aug 23 2016 18:24:59
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Checking for update on startup
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Checking for available updates...
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1471977975, installed version 1471977975
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Nothing to do
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Verifying installation...
[2016-09-19 19:01:27] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2016-09-19 19:01:28] Verification complete
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
miguel@miguel-ThinkPad-X230:~$
```

So yeah... I don't know what is happening.
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 using a core-i5.

Comment: Does you get any descriptive errors if you run `STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam`? Please post the output if you do.

Comment: @GrannySez I was missing the 32-bit package version of libgtk2.0-0 and libxtst6. After I installed those, STEAM_RUNTIME throws no error, but still it won't open.

Comment: What commandline are you using? Try using `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose steam` and check the output. Have a look at this page for more details ... [https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/](https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/). Even though it's for AMD card some of the commands may help you debug. If you're still stuck give more details (system specs, output from commands, graphics card details, etc)